# Java Non-Static Field Defaults?

Tags: java

I recently came across a piece of code:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getInstance().getLogger(SomeClass.class);
    private int whatever;

    // .. Rest of the class definition
}
```

And was blown away! This code compiles and runs beautifully!  I've only seen this kind of assignment performed on class variables (statics).  I was under the impression that in order to assign values to instance variables, one had to do so inside of a method. Wrong!

My question: **is this a way of overriding the Java default value for types?** For instance, in the example above, the `1ogger` field would ordinarily be assigned a value of `null` until assgined a value by a constructor/setter. Other types, such as primitives, all have their own built-in defaults, such as `booleans` which are by default `false`.

Is this just Java's way of letting you override built-in defaults? Otherwise, what the heck is this and why is it compiling?!?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with it. The declaration can include an assignment, and that's what you are doing - assigning an initial value to your field.

You can give initial values to your fields in many ways: via constructor, via an initializer block (`{..}`) or by assigning the values directly, as you did.

See the [Initializing Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html) section of the tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the default value for a type, but you can write to instance variables in:

- Field declarations:

  ```
  private int x = 10;
  ```
- Constructors:

  ```
  private int x;
  public Foo() {
      x = 10;
  }
  ```
- Instance initializers:

  ```
  private int x;

  void someOtherMethod() {}

  // These are relatively rare
  {
      x = 10;
  }
  ```
- Normal methods:

  ```
  private int x;

  void someMethod() {
      x = 10;
  }
  ```

See [section 8.3.2.2](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.2.2) of the JLS for more on initializers for instance variables, as well as [section 8.3](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3) of the JLS for more general syntax of field declaration.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in defaults cannot be overriden, int fields are initialized to zero for instance. You can do nothing about that (apart from initializing the field to other value yourself)